# django clean multiple fields at once

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with a start date and end date. How do I clean the form so that the end date comes after the start date. I can clean one field, but not sure how to clean a field while comparing it to another field. Also, when this errors out, I'd like to be able to have the error render in the `{{ form.end_date.errors }}` as opposed to a general section. Is there a way to do that with `forms.ValidationError`

```
class ContractChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']

        if end_date < start_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Error: The ending date must come after the starting date.',code='invalid_date')
        return end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the error to a specific field with `add_error()` method:

```
if end_date < start_date:
   self.add_error('field_name','Error text message....')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by passing a `dict`

```
raise forms.ValidationError({'end_date': u'Error: The ending date must come after the starting date.'})
```